# Add a key with colon to a Counter

Tags: python, key, counter

I want to add a key to a Counter object that has several colon (:) characters inside. The problem is Counter object adds a key for every character in my key. for example:

```
>>> cc = Counter()
>>> cc.update("1:2:3")
>>> cc
Counter({':':2, '1':1, '2':1, '3':1})
```

I want my counter be like `Counter({'1:2:3':1})`. How can I do that?

Comment: Actually, that solution does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert a dictionary into the Counter update, like this:

```
from collections import Counter
cc = Counter()
cc.update({"1:2:3":1})
print cc
'Counter({'1:2:3': 1})'
```

Answer (score 2):

`Counter.update(iterable)` takes an iterable (hint: a Python string IS an iterable) and updates the count for each item of the iterable - so what you get is really what is to be expected.

If you really want to use `Counter.update()` here, you have to pass either a dict with `'1:2:3'` as key and `1` as value or a sequence of `(key, value)` tuples (ie `[("1:2:3", 1),]`).

Else you can *of course* use the ordinary dict syntax as mentioned by Daniel Roseman - which really is the thing to do if you have no other reason to use `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

A Counter is basically a dict. So you can set your key via the normal dict syntax:

```
cc["1:2:3"] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @danielRoseman, but consider situation that I want to use the `update()` function. Is there any way to prevent update from splitting the input key?